# Thymeleaf submit form caused KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

I used Java at first. Today I convert my Java code to Kotlin code and there's an error occured. When I submit the form, Thymeleaf shows `Invalid property 'details[0]' of bean class [org.example.website.model.Record]` and the debug console tells me that a KotlinNullPointerException was thrown from `Record.getDetails`. I set a breakpoint in the getter, and find that the object I submit is not the same one I set to Model's Attribute. The details property of the object is null.
Hopes this problem can be resolved. Thanks very much.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
class Record {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "record", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
    var details: List<Detail>? = null
        get() {
            return field!!.sortedBy { it.value }
        }

    var instruction: Long? = null
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/page")
fun page(model: Model): String {
        // for form submission
        val record = Record()
        record.details = listOf(Detail(), Detail())
        model.addAttribute("record", record)

        return "page"
    }
}
```

page.html

```
<form th:action="@{/handle}" th:object="${record}" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <table class="table">
        <tr th:each="detail, state: ${record.details}">
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{details[__${state.index}__].value}" required="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Finish</button>
<form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are initializing a field to `null` and then telling Kotlin that you know it's not null (because of the `!!` operator)...

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "record", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
var details: List<Detail>? = null
    get() {
        return field!!.sortedBy { it.value }
    }
```

What this says is, define a field called `details` as a nullable `List<Detail>`, originally initialized to `null`. When somebody calls `get()`, ignore the null check on the possibly null `field` (which is `details) and sort the values.

You probably need something like this, instead (untested):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "record", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
var details: List<Detail>? = null
    get() {
        return field?.sortedBy { it.value } 
    }
```

This will either return you a sorted list or a `null`.

Comment: I tried it just now. Your answer has worked very well. Thank you very much!